# Is the use of Beethoven's 5th in "Before the Flood" a reference to the Master?

Tags: doctor-who

In "Before the Flood," the Doctor discusses the Bootstrap Paradox using the works of Ludwig van Beethoven as an example.  After that, he plays the opening motif of Beethoven's 5th symphony as an example.  [Listen to it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4IRMYuE1hI).

Were these four notes--probably the most famous motif in all of music--a reference to the drums in the Master's head and the whole "He will knock 4 times" thing from Tennant?

Comment: ... why would you think that, other than the number 4?

Comment: @Radhil In fairness, that [motif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._5_(Beethoven)#Fate_motif) is sometimes called "Fate knocking at the door"

Comment: @JasonBaker - Huh. So appropriate question,  whether intended or not. Learn something new every day.